# Why my responsive web template dosen't work on cellphones?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Yesterday I created wordpress theme using bootstrap  and I checked in my computer and it was working properly . 
But when I upload that theme on my host and open my website on my cellphone theme didn't work!!

check my website to  take a look for my theme : www.amircoding.ir

If you visit my website using your computer everything will be fine and theme working properly but if you visit my website using your cellphone you will see my theme doesn't work properly I mean my theme responsive is not working . I use bootstrap to creat this theme but I don't know where is problem . please help me.
Thanks

p.e : You can see my websites source through right click and 'view page source'.

Comment: Your question is somehow ambiguous. What do you mean by not working?! The images of the website are not loading in both environments, pc, and cellphone. In order to achieve a proper answer, you might need to ask your question in details. [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: thanks brother now I change my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add this inside your `<head>` `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

So your `<head>` will like this

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
.........
.........
.........
</head>
```

it will fix on your mobile viewport.

Check out this [source](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/#template)

Comment: Thnaks my brother . Now everything is fine , thanks for your helping.